# How can Block receive Email in Android?

Tags: android, email

I made Connection setting in my Emulator for Gmail Ac...It's work
It shown me all the Inbox Messge.
Now I want to delete coming Message from my Emulator(or Device),It remain as it is at Gmail Ac.

Can any one help me.

Thanx

Answer (score 1):

You cannot "receive Email in Android" unless you write an email client and have users use that instead of Email, Gmail, K9, etc.

Comment: Thanx for Reply 
I open my Gmail A/c in my Emulator ,Now I want to Remove Incoming mail from my A/c Inbox